# A-Frame <a-sky> object dynamic background

Tags: aframe

How can I add a dynamic background visual for `<a-sky>` object?
Especially I want to add a 3d map view to  object.

I try assets manager with image object:

```
<!-- <a-assets>
<img id="sky"/>

</a-assets>
<a-sky src="#sky"></a-sky> -->
```

However it shows a black screen. It probably because `<img />` element only accepts 2d images/resources.

Many thanks...

Comment: 3d map view? What extension does it have?

Comment: Sorry but I don't know the extension. It is a Bing map from cesiumjs

Answer (score 0):

Don't need to use `<a-assets>` and `<img>` if it's dynamic. Just set the src.

```
document.querySelector('a-sky').setAttribute('src', 'img.png');
```

Comment: It is not a 2d view I am trying to put a 3d map.